# High speed, high precision motors for a Spherical Parallel Manipulator

Tags: motor, servomotor, stepper-motor, brushless-motor

As the title says, I am looking for motors suitable for my Spherical Parallel Manipulator.

The Spherical Parallel Manipulator will have a camera (likely a DLSR) mounted to it. The motors need to be accurate so because I need camera pointing to be accurate. Servo motors comes to mind, but I need speed: the camera should be able to do 180 degrees in less than a second.

I have been out of electronics for a long, long time, so I would really appreciate some help in selecting the motor.

Comment: Its not too difficult to find servo's capable of 180 degrees / second or faster, so that would personally be my recommendation given that you want precision, and presumably ease of use.  Depending on your requirements and budget, I've found Dynamixel servos to be great (not an ad, just a fan). They have many models for a range of torques and speeds (most over 60rpm / 360deg/s), nice and easy control interfaces, etc. That said, they're definitely on the pricier side. You could probably find some high torque RC servos for a fraction of the price with similar specs.

Comment: @shonigmann Thanks! I will take a look at Dynamixel servos.